# Summarize Gaps in Binary Data using R

Tags: r, analytics

I am playing around with binary data.

I have data in columns in the following manner:

```
       A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N
       -----------------------------------------------------
       1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
       0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   0
       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
```

1 - Indicating that the system was on and 0 indicating that the system was off

I am trying to figure out ways to figure out a way to summarize the gaps between the on/off transition of these systems.

For example,
for the first row, it stops working after 'I'
for the second row, it works from  'E' to 'G' and then works again in 'I' and 'M' but is off during other.

Is there a way to summarize this?

I wish to see my result in the following form

```
    row-number    Number of 1's       Range
    ------------  ------------------  ------
    1                    9             A-I
    2                    3             E-G
    2                    2             I-J
    2                    1             M
    3                    5             H-L
```

Comment: Not clear about the expected output.  Do you need the total count of consecutive 1s? `apply(df1, 1, function(x) sum(rle(x)$values == 1))`

Comment: How do you want to **summarise** it ? You need to provide an expected output such as of table or graphs.

Comment: @yifyan I have made the edits

Comment: @akrun could you please refer the updated post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  gather(col, val, -rowid) %>%
  group_by(rowid) %>%
  # This counts the number of times a new streak starts
  mutate(grp_num = cumsum(val != lag(val, default = -99))) %>%
  filter(val == 1) %>%
  group_by(rowid, grp_num) %>%
  summarise(num_1s = n(),
            range = paste0(first(col), "-", last(col)))


## A tibble: 5 x 4
## Groups:   rowid [3]
#  rowid grp_num num_1s range
#  <int>   <int>  <int> <chr>
#1     1       1      9 A-I  
#2     2       2      3 E-G  
#3     2       4      2 I-J  
#4     2       6      1 M-M  
#5     3       2      5 H-L
```

Comment: How do I do the same thing to calculate the streaks of zeros?

Comment: Replace `filter(val == 1) %>%` with `filter(val == 0) %>%`. If you want both, delete that line and use `group_by(rowid, val, grp_num) %>%` in the next line.

Comment: Thanks! If the quantity of zeros is less than 1, I'd like to count it as 1 and not zero. Just as in row 3, I want to see 5 ones instead of 4 in the middle. Basically I want to ignore a single zero in a streak of 1

Answer (score 2):

An option with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' while creating a row number column (`setDT`), `melt` from 'wide' to 'long' format specifying the `id.var` as row number column 'rn', create a run-lenght-id (`rleid`) column on the 'value' column grouped by 'rn', subset the rows where 'value' is 1, summarise with number of rows (`.N`), and `paste`d `range` of 'variable' values, grouped by 'grp' and 'rn', assign the columns not needed to `NULL` and `order` by 'rn' if necessary.

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df1, keep.rownames = TRUE), id.var = 'rn')[,
   grp := rleid(value), rn][value == 1, .(NumberOfOnes = .N,
    Range = paste(range(as.character(variable)), collapse="-")),
      .(grp, rn)][,  grp := NULL][order(rn)]
#   rn NumberOfOnes Range
#1:  1            9   A-I
#2:  2            3   E-G
#3:  2            2   I-J
#4:  2            1   M-M
#5:  3            5   H-L
```

---

Or using `base R` with `rle`

```
do.call(rbind, apply(df1, 1, function(x) {
       rl <- rle(x)
       i1 <- rl$values == 1
       l1 <- rl$lengths[i1]
       nm1 <- tapply(names(x), rep(seq_along(rl$values), rl$lengths),
          FUN = function(y) paste(range(y), collapse="-"))[i1]
       data.frame(NumberOfOnes = l1, Range = nm1)}))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 0L, 0L), B = c(1L, 0L, 0L), C = c(1L, 
0L, 0L), D = c(1L, 0L, 0L), E = c(1L, 1L, 0L), F = c(1L, 1L, 
0L), G = c(1L, 1L, 0L), H = c(1L, 0L, 1L), I = c(1L, 1L, 1L), 
    J = c(0L, 1L, 1L), K = c(0L, 0L, 1L), L = c(0L, 0L, 1L), 
    M = c(0L, 1L, 0L), N = c(0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate it. Unfortunately, I can only accept 1 answer